# pass info from one Dojo AMD module to another

Tags: ajax, json, dojo, amd

I am playing with modules in Dojo 1.8 and I have a module defined like this:

```
define(["dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/json"],
  function(xhr, JSON) {

  var url = "server/provider.php";

  return {
    files: {},

    getDirList: function() {
      var self = this;
      xhr(url).then(function(response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        // would love to return the JSON for use here
      }, function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
    }
  };

});
```

I have another module in which I'd love to call that method and then use it:

```
define(["dojo/dom",
        "dojo/dom-construct",
        "dojo/_base/array",
        "afm/utils"
        ],
function(dom,domConst,array, utils) {
  return {
    produceHtml: function() {
      var json = utils.getDirList(); //this returns undefined
      var dirLength = json.length;
      console.log(json);
      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        if(i % 2 === 0) {
          domConst.place('<tr class="even"><td>' + json[i].name + '</td></tr>', 'output');
        } else {
          domConst.place('<tr><td>' + json[i].name + '</td></tr>', 'output');
        }
      }

    }
  };
});
```

Naturally I could just put the DOM creation code INTO the util module, but that is mixing view logic where it shouldn't be. And it's hideous if I want to reuse the util.getDirList method.

How can I use the JSON that gets returned by that method? Is anyone else doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the dojo/request/xhr call comes in asynchronously, so setting the response parameter is done only after returning. 
What you want is return a Promise (read up here: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/promises/ ).

But first of all: you can make the dojo/request parse the json data for you, as follows:

```
require(['dojo/request'],function(request) {
    request.get('http://example.com/data.json', {handleAs:'json'}).then(...)
})
```

See here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/request.html#dojo-request

Now combining this, your getDirList function could be just:

```
getDirList: function() {
    return xhr.get(url, {handleAs:'json'});
}
```

And then in your produceHtml you would do something like this:

```
utils.getDirList.then(function(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    if(i % 2 === 0) {
      domConst.place('<tr class="even"><td>' + json[i].name + '</td></tr>', 'output');
    } else {
      domConst.place('<tr><td>' + json[i].name + '</td></tr>', 'output');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It's always that asynchronous thing that gets me. I probably shouldn't touch Node.js much until I get a decent handle on that!

Comment: Only thing I would add is the method call needs parenthesis. utils.getDirList().then(function(json).... etc

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Jim. But we don't just copy-paste from SO or do we ;)

Comment: Ha, I missed this response. I know plenty of people that DO c/p from SO!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your second module, shouldn't

```
define(["dojo/dom",
        "dojo/dom-construct",
        "dojo/_base/array",
        "afm/utils"
        ],
function(dom,domConst,array) {
```

become

```
define(["dojo/dom",
        "dojo/dom-construct",
        "dojo/_base/array",
        "afm/utils"
        ],
function(dom,domConst,array, utils) {
```

?

Comment: Yes, I should edit my example. This was just a quick example reverted from what I have working now. (I am including the HTML generation code in the callback - so you're seeing the remnants of that). Doing what you're suggesting doesn't allow me to see the return of the utils.getDirList method though.

Comment: Ok I think I understand your question better. You could do it like this :

`var myData = '';
xhr(url, {
 handleAs: "json"
 }).then(function(data){
 myData = data;
});
return myData;`

Comment: I was trying to get the module to simply be a class for querying and giving a raw result. I haven't played with Dojo much and typically in jQuery my callbacks handle the result directly (parse the JSON and populate some HTML) I wanted to decouple that. The asynchronous nature of JS takes a bit more thought though.